# wp_remote_post returns an error on SSL connection

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I'm using [`wp_remote_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post) to post some info to a secure connection like this

```
$url = 'https://example.com/path/file.json';    

wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'sslverify' => false,
    'timeout'   => 60,
    'body'      => $body,
));
```

But I get an error:

```
SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled
```

I though `sslverify`set to `false` should prevent that?

If I set `sslverify => true` it works but may cause problems on other servers

Here's the complete wp_error object:

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors:WP_Error:private] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled
                )

        )

    [error_data:WP_Error:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Maybe it's related but on Apache 2.2 it works while on Apache 2.4 it doesn't

Comment: Having this same issue... I think this is due to some CURL / PHP updates?

Comment: Are you running OS X?

Comment: Yes, OSX 10.10 and local development

Comment: Yep, same.  Thinking it's when I did brew updates it kind of was patched therefor breaking my nice setup :X

Comment: ...have you tried setting `'sslverify' => true,`? The error you're getting states that `certificate verification is disabled`...which is why I'm suggesting enabling it.

Comment: yes, `sslverify` to `true` works but not on all servers

Comment: ...there's not going to be a one-off solution that works on all servers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your Apache 2.2 and 2.4 configurations are different. On 2.4 you probably have SSLVerifyClient set to required which would cause it to act like what you are describing. You'd need to set it to none:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLVerifyClient

Comment: How can I change this setting?

Comment: It should be in the httpd.conf file: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol